# What's the difference between a JavaScript function and a React hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've been looking into writing my own React hooks but so far am struggling to tell on a technical level what the difference is between a normal JavaScript function and a hook.

For example, [this](https://blog.bitsrc.io/writing-your-own-custom-hooks-4fbcf77e112e) article says hooks are "normal JavaScript functions which can use other hooks inside of it", but what else is going on under the hood?

I know that we use the word `use` in the hook name, but I'm curious what it is about hooks that make them hooks and not functions!

Comment: Custom hooks usually call other hooks inside them.

Comment: Thanks, but couldn't I just do this with functions?

Comment: Please go through this example from the documentation:https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook

Comment: What makes a function a hook is that React somehow keeps track of the function call. This allows React to persist state (generic state, not React state) across function calls. In other words, React is able to associate a function call (and its input and output) with a specific React element.

Comment: Keep in mind that hooks are genetically implemented as callbacks.  That is the framework calls a particular function that you register with it.  So you will write the hook with the correct type as per react’s definition and tell react to call that function by passing a reference to the function to react.

Comment: @adiga not true, in the react docs it says that custom hooks may have other hooks inside of them.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> what it is about hooks that make them hooks and not functions!

Hooks are functions. What's special about them is what their purpose is and when they're supposed to be used. Their purpose is to give you a way to interact with the react component lifecycle, and they are implemented so that they work correctly only if they are called while a functional component is rendering.

The react team implemented several of these ([15 at time of writing](https://react.dev/reference/react)). They let you do things like manage state or run side effects. You can mix and match these any way you like, and if you put the code into a helper method, this is referred to as a "custom hook".

Answer (score 2):

React hooks are not in any way introduced to be different from JavaScript functions. They are introduced to give the power of class components to functional components.

For example, you cannot have any sort of local state management inside a functional component, you'd have to convert it into a class component if you are in need to introduce state. Now with the introduction of hooks, you can use [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to give functional component the power of class component's state management.

Comment: Thanks, but why couldn't I just write functions called from inside my functional component instead of using hooks if this is the case?

Comment: I guess you can declare the functions outside the functional component and use them. If you declare the functions inside the functional component, it will be defined in each render, will not be reused. We can use useCallback hook to memoize the functions to make it reusable to a degree.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Explanation:

Javascript Functions - Method or instructions to the browsers to fire some events when called or required.

React Hooks - These are also Javascript Functions just its based on some life cycle of the library. React hooks combines a bunch of methods(functions) like componentsDidMount(),componentDidLoad() etc... and wrap it all in one.